# How to access current route from anywhere in my app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I am trying to get information about the current route on a non-Route component.

> React Router provides singleton versions of history (browserHistory
>   and hashHistory) that you can import and use from anywhere in your
>   application.

Previously, it would seem you could use `browserHistory`, but that no longer appears to be supported.  I'm using `react-router-redux^4.0.8` and `@types\react-router-redux^5.0.1`.

How can I access the current route location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple. You can use the [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) HOC

> You can get access to the history object's properties and the closest
>   **Route**'s match via the **withRouter** higher-order component. withRouter
>   will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped
>   component whenever it renders.

It is used liked this:

```
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom"
@withRouter
class NonRouteComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    // you have access to this.props.match
    // you have access to this.props.history
    // you have access to this.props.location
    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    return <h1>Hi {location.pathname}</h1>;
  }
}
```

If you don't use decorators aka @withRouter you can export the component like so:

```
class NonRouteComponent extends Component { ... }
export default withRouter(NonRouteComponent);
```

Comment: I edited my answer. You're supposed to import it from react-router-dom

Comment: Thanks! Bonus question: How can I pass additional information on a `Route` eg. what area of the application it should be associated with?  I'm looking to be able to group routes together based on area.

Comment: @im1dermike I suggest using something like this:

<Route path="/admin" component={AdminRoutes} />

and then AdminRoutes would have another Switch and maybe a layout for all your admin routes.

<Container>
  <Sidebar />
  <Switch>
    <Route ......... />
    <Route ......... />
  </Switch>
</Container>